# RxJS Http Server with typescript compile errors

Tags: node.js, typescript, http, rxjs

I'm pretty newbie with rxjs, can you please tell what's wrong with below?

```
interface IHTTP {
    req: IncomingMessage;
    res: ServerResponse;
    handler?: Promise<any>;
}
server = http.createServer();
  let request$: Observable<any>;
  request$ = fromEvent(server, 'request').pipe(
    map(([req, res]: [IncomingMessage, ServerResponse]): IHTTP => {
        return { req, res } as IHTTP;
      }
    )
  );
```

Compile error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<[IncomingMessage, ServerResponse], IHTTP>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, IHTTP>'.   Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '[IncomingMessage, ServerResponse]'.
```

Comment: This's neither related with angular nor http client, as I stated in the title, it's for HTTP server. @RichardRublev

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem I had to define fromEvent's first argument as:

```
server as FromEventTarget<[http.IncomingMessage, http.ServerResponse]>
```

Otherwise Typescript thinks it's `FromEventTarget<unknown>`